# Перевод десятичного числа в двоичное JS

Tags: javascript

не подскажите как в JS перевести десятичное число в двоичное? Запрещено использовать toString, что немного усложняет задачу, особенно для новичков.

Рылся по другим тема и для JS'а вроде как не обнаружил подобного решения, заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function toBase(value, base) {
  if (base != Math.round(base))
    throw "Base is not valid: " + base;
  // TODO: define digits above 9
  var result = "";
  while (value) {
    result = value % base + result;
    value = Math.floor(value / base);
  }
  return result;
}

function toBinary(value) {
  return toBase(value, 2);
}

console.log(toBinary(10));
console.log(toBinary(33));
console.log(toBinary(100));
console.log(toBinary(128));

console.log(toBase(128, 10));
console.log(toBase(128, 10.5));
```

Comment: `toBase(1, 1)`? :)